# Drupal Media Gallery module not playing uploaded videos? Ideas

Tags: drupal, module, gallery, colorbox, media

I am using Media Gallery module on a Drupal 7 installation to create some mixed picture and video galleries. I am having trouble with the module as it seems that it will not play my uploaded videos, but if i check my media library and view the file itself it plays. What is there to do ?

Comment: Please explain why it will not play the videos. I have not used the media module, but looking at the source code in the html should give you a clue why it wont play.

Comment: the player is not working, it says that i should use a different module for the player "Media Element". The thing is that media gallery is working fine, except when it is supposed to play a video it just displays an icon. If i search for that particular file in the media library and try to access it, it plays.

Comment: accessing a file directly and accessing it while embedded on a html page are very different. It sounds like you need a module to do the embedding.